# Interpretation of How much less

Tags: meaning

> If it was not useful for anything when it was whole, **how much less** can it be made into something **useful** when the fire has burned it and it is charred?

-- [Ezekiel 15-5 NIV](https://www.biblestudytools.com/ezekiel/15.html)

I can't make sense of this sentence.  I think the intended meaning is:  It would be much less useful when it is burned.  But if that is the case "how much less useful" shouldn't come separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the meaning: it must be less useful now that it's been burned than it was before it was burned, probably because it cannot even be used as fuel anymore.

Bible language --even modern translations like this one-- is often unnatural, and this is the case here. The sentence can only be understood by inferring the meaning from the context and piecing together that it's a *rhetorical question*, and the answer you're supposed to infer is that it can only be less useful now that it's been burned.